# How to write a test to expose returning a task from a using block?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

I wrote the following buggy async method, which passes its unit test but fails in production (**EDIT:** in production it throws an `ObjectDisposedException`):

```
public class FileUtils {
    public Task<string> ReadAllText(string path)
    {
        using (var stream = ReadStreamAsync(path))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    private static FileStream ReadStreamAsync(string path)
    {
        return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous);
    }
}
```

The error is that if you return a task from inside a `using` block, the code will only work if the `ReadToEndAsync` call happens to execute synchronously (which apparently happened in my unit test).

The correct code adds `async` and `await` as follows:

```
    public async Task<string> ReadAllText(string path)
    {
        using (var stream = ReadStreamAsync(path))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
```

My question is: **How would I write a unit test that would reliably fail for the incorrect version of the code?**

**EDIT:** Here is the current (insufficient) unit test that does not expose this problem:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task GivenFileUtilsWhenReadAllTextThenGetsText()
    {            
        var fileUtils = new FileUtils(); // the prod code above is in class FileUtils
        var path = @"C:\tmp\foo.txt";
        var expected = "foo";
        File.WriteAllText(path, expected);

        var text = await fileUtils.ReadAllText(path);

        text.Should().Be(expected);
    }
```

Comment: Well, not necessarily, although that would be fine.  I just want the unit test to fail.

Comment: Well updated question. Reviewing.

Comment: Ok ran some tests. Your code is fine. The problem is that you do not put enough content in the file to cause it to be disposed. It's finishing too quickly

Comment: I just added more content `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                expected += expected;
            }` before writing to the file and ran the test and sure enough object disposed exception.

Comment: Is this an option? Replace your entire method with `System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync(path)`. Now it's not your code and you don't have to write a test for it.

Comment: @ScottHannen... not yet... it's preview

Answer (score 1):

> How would I write a unit test that would reliably fail for the incorrect version of the code?

Frame it in terms of requirements. This is what you want to test:

"The SUT should not dispose the stream immediately. It may dispose the stream after the stream has been completely read."

In order to do this, your unit test needs to control:

1. The stream being disposed, so it can detect when disposal happens.
2. When the stream is completely read.

Both of these can be handled using a custom stream type.

For the first stub requirement, your custom stream type can just have a `bool Disposed` property that is set to `true` when `Dispose` is called.

For the second stub requirement, your custom stream type can be implemented to only complete asynchronous operations after a signal is received. One type for an "asynchronous signal" is `TaskCompletionSource<T>` - you can create the instance inside the custom stream, have every `async` method `await` its `Task` property, and when your unit test is ready for the stream to complete, it can complete the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

Comment: That would require refactoring the SUT to be able to manipulate stream. That was the only way I was seeing it being done given the tight coupling of current code.

Comment: What is the SUT?

Comment: SUT = System Under Test. In this case, `FileUtils.ReadAllText`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not put enough content in the file to cause it to be disposed when read asynchronously.

So it is not that your code executed synchronously. It's finishing its task too quickly to cause the issue experienced in production.

To prove it, I just added more content

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { expected += expected; }
```

before writing to the file and ran the test

```
var fileUtils = new FileUtils(); // the prod code above is in class FileUtils
var path = @"foo.txt";
var expected = "foo";
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    expected += expected;
}
File.WriteAllText(path, expected);

var text = await fileUtils.ReadAllText(path);

text.Should().Be(expected);
```

and sure enough object disposed exception caused the a failed test.

You have already discovered the solution to the problem code by awaiting within the `using` block.

Writing tests to discover what you seek would be rather difficult, however Code Analyzers would have a better chance of discovering such mistakes at compile time.

Comment: So just make the content longer?  But it's still not guaranteed to fail, right?  That approach will always be system dependent, it seems

Comment: This test does prove that the original code was flawed in a failed test.